# Error: Server error

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1

When I try to export 1000 products for example since of Catalog-> Manage products-> Action(Export products) return a error page:
[image]
[image: Erro: server Error]

Any idea?

Comment: Are you using an extension for this? That's not a native option for the product grid action drop down.

Comment: Yes, I create this extension for do this. The problem is when i try to export a lot of products to CSV